# How to make the Controller get the "LinkText" Text from @ Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

In my application came the need to have a same Controller named Classification have the function of Reclassification, with this, I want the Controller Class to receive the LinkText string from @Html.ActionLink to be able to control the visibility of some html components of my View, being they columns of the existing table in the View Index and also control the visibility of some fields in the Views Insert, Details and Delete

Getting the links

```
@Html.ActionLink("Classification", "Index", "Classification")
@Html.ActionLink("Reclassification", "Index", "Classification")
```

I want my Controller to take the Rating and Reclassification value and send via ViewBag to the Views and thus control the visibilities involved.

Comment: Then you need to add it as a route value, or query string value (e.g. `@Html.ActionLink("Classification", "Index", "Classification", new { text = "Classification" }, null)`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - how do I get the ViewBag to get this value from the link?

Comment: What does `ViewBag` have to do with your question? - your method just needs to be `public ActionResult Classification(string text)` and the value of `text` will be the value you passed in the link

Comment: Adding to @StephenMuecke's reply
@Html.ActionLink("Classification", "Index", "Classification", new { text = ViewBag.BlaBla }, null))